# how to resample accumulated data by seconds and reset at every day using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have daily accumulated data like below. It resets to 0 at the start of every day(00:00:00).

```
index
11/05 23:59:48  100
11/05 23:59:59  150
11/06 00:00:01  10
11/06 00:00:02  20
11/06 00:00:12  40
```

I need to get the absolute(not accumulate) number during 10seconds like below.

```
index
11/05 23:59:49  Nan
11/05 23:59:59  50
11/06 00:00:09  20
11/06 00:00:19  20
```

I did something like below, but it gives Nan value at the first period(eg : 11/06 00:00:09) of every day.

```
df.groupby(df.index.levels[0].dt).resample('10S').last().diff()
```

```
index
11/05 23:59:49  Nan
11/05 23:59:59  50
11/06 00:00:09  Nan
11/06 00:00:19  20
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the difference directly without `groupby` after resampling.
The beginning of days can be detected by a `diff-ne` construct, and the required correction at these locations can be made by adding the previous cumulative value back.

**Data**

The index here is `pd.Timestamp`.

```
print(df)
                     total
index                     
2020-11-05 23:59:48    100
2020-11-05 23:59:59    150
2020-11-06 00:00:01     10
2020-11-06 00:00:02     20
2020-11-06 00:00:12     40
```

**Code**

```
# Not accurate for the test data, so replaced
# df2 = df.resample("10S").last()

df2 = df.copy()
df2["new_index"] = df2.index.map(lambda ts: ts + pd.Timedelta(9 - ts.second % 10, unit="s"))
df2 = df2.groupby("new_index").last()

# 1. de-accumulate without groupby
df2["diff"] = df2.diff()
# 2. get date change locations (where diff != 0 Days)
df2["date"] = df2.index.date
df2["add"] = df2["date"].diff().ne("0D")
# 3. add the previous total back
df2.loc[df2["add"], "diff"] += df2["total"].shift()[df2["add"]]
```

**Result**

The `diff` column is what you want.

```
print(df2)
                     total  diff        date    add
new_index                                          
2020-11-05 23:59:49    100   NaN  2020-11-05   True
2020-11-05 23:59:59    150  50.0  2020-11-05  False
2020-11-06 00:00:09     20  20.0  2020-11-06   True
2020-11-06 00:00:19     40  20.0  2020-11-06  False
```

Tested on python 3.7.9 and pandas 1.1.3

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I have one more index which is company id. Anyway I will try with your solution.